# How to keep UITableViewController with background transparent like "lightbox"

Tags: uitableview, ios7, transparent

I am programming an app which at home screen there is a mapview and a button.
When user taps the button the app will show a uitableview controller, but this table might have only a few items, so I would like to do like a "lightbox" effect keeping the previous view at the background.

I tried setting these things but a black screen is displayed.

```
[self.tableView setOpaque:NO];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Ideas?

Comment: How are you presenting the UITableViewController?

Comment: I connected a button to the UITableViewController with a segue in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting the UITableViewController in the normal way, there is nothing behind the table view to show when you do make it transparent. You will need to manually put the view on top of the previous view if you want the user to be able to see through to it.

You will also need to make the cells themselves transparent because starting in iOS 7, they are opaque by default.

Comment: Thank you! But it's possible maintain the NavigationBar?

Comment: When you add the UITableViewcontroller's view to the current view it doesn't have to cover up the navigation bar so yes you can keep it.

Comment: I understand now... So the design needs to be revised. It no make sense to me have a navigation bar with back button in the uitableview controller with transparent background using cover effect. Thanks!